# How to reload jquery so that it will works for the next process

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a problem to run a second process that run under JQuery as the code below.

```
<html>
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /></head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src='jquery-1.6.2.min.js'> </script>
    <div id="displayArea1">
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div id="displayArea2">
    </div>
    <input id="btnSet" type="button" value="Set The Value" />
    <script>

        //The input that should i use
        var itemToPrintOut1 = "[Input1 (working)]     Search <strong style='cursor:pointer' title='Click here'>IP{<span id='ip1'>192.168.2.56,192.168.2.89,192.168.2.75</span>}</strong> that has accessed to MAIL-SERVER{192.168.2.8}";
        var itemToPrintOut2 = "[Input2 (not working)] Search <strong style='cursor:pointer' title='Click here'>IP{<span id='ip2'>192.168.2.56,192.168.2.89,192.168.2.75</span>}</strong> that has accessed to MAIL-SERVER{192.168.2.8}";

        $("#displayArea1").html(itemToPrintOut1);  //If I enable this line, it is works as what i want(because it is using jquery)

        $("#btnSet").click(function(){
            $("#displayArea2").html(itemToPrintOut2);
        });

        $("#ip1").click(function(){
            alert("Normal method, data = " + $("#ip1").html());
        });

        $("#ip2").click(function(){
            alert("The method I should use, data = " + $("#ip2").html());
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

The first time(while loading) it will display `itemToPrintOut1` text and I can click on the IP address. I have no issue on that!

But when i click the button and display the second text `itemToPrintOut2`, I cannot click the IP anymore.

Can anyone help me on how to make sure the second output can be used with JQUERY as well. There is so many things that is also related to this issues to me. 
Is it related to JQuery loading?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use .live() instead of .click() for binding events at run-time. Since .live() is deprecated you may want to try .on() method.

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to bind a handler to an element that doesn't already exist, try this:

```
<script>

    //The input that should i use
    var itemToPrintOut1 = "[Input1 (working)]     Search <strong style='cursor:pointer' title='Click here'>IP{<span id='ip1'>192.168.2.56,192.168.2.89,192.168.2.75</span>}</strong> that has accessed to MAIL-SERVER{192.168.2.8}";
    var itemToPrintOut2 = "[Input2 (not working)] Search <strong style='cursor:pointer' title='Click here'>IP{<span id='ip2'>192.168.2.56,192.168.2.89,192.168.2.75</span>}</strong> that has accessed to MAIL-SERVER{192.168.2.8}";

    $("#displayArea1").html(itemToPrintOut1);  //If I enable this line, it is works as what i want(because it is using jquery)

    $("#btnSet").click(function(){
        $("#displayArea2").html(itemToPrintOut2);

         $("#ip2").click(function(){
               alert("The method I should use, data = " + $("#ip2").html());
         });
    });

    $("#ip1").click(function(){
        alert("Normal method, data = " + $("#ip1").html());
    });

</script>
```

Then when you click in `ip1`, it adds `ip2` html and his handler.

Answer (score 1):

When you add the click event onto ip2, it doesn't exist. You can use the jquery 'live' that will bind an event onto anything that appears later on the page.

```
$('#ip2').live('click',function() {});
```

And that will bind the click event on any dom elements that are added to the document later on if they have id of 'ip2'